# how to referencing a script from a different GameObject, without GetComponent?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Normally I use GameObject then GetComponent.

```
GameObject instati = GameObject.Find("INS");
instati.GetComponent<Script>().number = 5;
```

is that a way to directly use Script like below?

```
Script.number = 5
```

Comment: If you do this via the Inspector yes: `public Script ins;` -> drag your object into this slot in the Inspector -> `ins.number = 5;` ... I would strongly discourage from using `static` out of being lazy ... But sure you *could* make number `static` then you can directly do `Script.number = 5;` ..

Comment: Static could do as mentioned, if there is only one INS object. If you start having many of them, then the number value will be same for all.

Comment: Search for Unity + Singleton design pattern

Answer (score 0):

No, there can be multiple "scripts" on different objects that are independent of each other, and if you don't specify which one objects Unity doesn't know you want which one "scripts". use transfrom.find instead of GameObject.find